# Received memory warning in camera UIImagePickerController (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to decrease the memory when using the code below for the UIImagePickerController? The strange thing is that the memory is not coming above 26MB but it still shows the received memory warning. After taking a picture the app crashes. Memory warning only shows when choosing the camera, when choosing the library it's just fine.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex){
        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:type]){
        if(buttonIndex==0 && [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
            type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.delegate   = self;
        picker.sourceType = type;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CLImageEditor *editor = [[CLImageEditor alloc] initWithImage:image];
    editor.delegate = self;

    [picker pushViewController:editor animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: *Your* app is using 26MB but the memory of all apps currently running on the operating system is too high, which triggers a memory warning. The image picker isn't running inside your app, so it doesn't count towards your memory usage, however you are triggering the image picker so you need to make sure there is enough memory available for it (by freeing up memory in your own app). What hardware and operating system are you running this on? It's not jail broken or iOS 8 or something?

Comment: Hi, running on iPhone 5s on iOS 7. It's not jailbroken. How can I see what is causing lot's of memory?

Comment: That's really weird then. I've only ever run into this problem on older devices with 256MB of RAM, or if it's jail  broken or iOS 8 perhaps there is a bug. Anyway you can see system-wide memory statistics with the `Product -> Profile` menu item in Xcode, then choose the "Activity Monitor" instrument.

Comment: It seems that my backboardd uses lots of CPU (26%) and ram (14MB) or are these normal values? Strange thing is also that the app doesn't crash on another iPhone 5s and the app itself is live and still didn't got any negatieve reviews about the crashing.

Comment: The 5s has 1024MB of RAM so there has to be something consuming around 800MB of memory when your app crashes. If it only happens on your phone maybe there is something in your photo library causing issues.

Comment: Did a hard reset and app is working now without memory warnings.

Comment: I've had same issue. A reboot fixed it.